# Monte Carlo simulation in VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a «general/standardized» macro for Monte Carlo simulation in VBA/Excel. I have been able to write a rather efficient code which works well in simple cases where the entire calculation/formula is written in one cell (with inputs from other cells). However, I am struggling to find a way to write an efficient code for more complex calculations.

Whenever I work with simulation in VBA/Excel, I always try to do all of the calculations in VBA and only get input/display output in Excel – in order to increase the speed of the simulations as much as possible. Unfortunately, for “complex” calculations (read: multiple calculations ultimately leading to one output), e.g. a discounted cash flow analysis where the output is the sum of the present value of projected cash flows for several years going forward and the cash flow for each year is based on several assumptions, it is quite time consuming and almost undoable to write all of the calculations in VBA. The only way to perform Monte Carlo simulations in such models that I have been able to think of is to write a loop where I change the desired input variable to a random draw from the appropriate distribution and recalculate the workbook for each run through the loop and store the result from each run in an output sheet.  Here is a very rough example code:

```
Sub MCDCF()

Dim i As Long, iterations As Long
Dim target As Range, variable As Range

With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .EnableEvents = False
                .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

iterations = Cells(5, 17).Value

Set target = Cells(28, 3)
Set variable = Cells(47, 3)

For i = 1 To iterations
    variable.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.NormInv(Rnd(), Cells(7, 17).Value, Cells(8, 17).Value)
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Cells(5 + i, 19).Value = target.Value
Next

With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .EnableEvents = True
                .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

The above approach is way too slow. Does anyone have any suggestions to an alternative approach?

Additional information: What I mean by “general/standardized” macro is that I will create a userform with RefEdit inputs for output cell, cell containing variable to be simulated and number of iterations – with the goal that the macro can be applied to several different Excel models.

And yes, I know that VBA/Excel is far from the best tool when it comes to simulations. However, it is the only alternative for the people that will be using this.

Comment: If the implementation of `NormInv` function is not known or you think it's not very performant, you could consider writing your own function (since it seems to be the main function that you're calling inside the loop). But before that, I would start off by reading the values on the sheet into numeric values (rather than range objects as you're currently doing), processing and outputting results to an  in-memory array (rather than writing to the sheet and calling `Application.Calculate` at each iteration), then writing back the array to the sheet in a single operation.

Comment: @chillin Thank you very much for your response. That sounds like some really good ideas, especially the last part of your comment. I am not really sure how to implement this. Can you give me some pointers or elaborate a bit on how you would read them as numeric values when they are "dynamic formulas" depending on several other cells in the sheet and particularly how they can be processed and stored in an in-memory array without needing to call Application.Calculate? If so, that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: How complicated is your worksheet? Do you think you could upload a screenshot with some annotations (showing what cells are changing, how the spreadsheet is before the code is run, and how it is after the code has been run, etc). Depending on how complicated the spreadsheet is, what I suggested may or may not be applicable, thanks.

Comment: A bit more information; in the example above, "target" is a sum formula including a range of several cells, where each cell in the sum range has several precedent calculations where some of the cells in one way or another is linked to "variable".

Comment: The models that I am planning on using the code on can get quite complicated  (dynamic bottom-up business forecast models). I can post a screenshot of the spreadsheet where I used the above code tomorrow morning if that is any help. (Haven't got it on this computer)

Comment: From what I can see, if you rely on the spreadsheet/formulas to do the calculations, it is likely that you'll benefit from multi-threaded calculation times and things will be easier to maintain but you'll then need to use VBA to interact with the spreadsheet for each iteration (which in itself is slow). Doing everything in memory using VBA means you lose out on multi-threaded calculation and it might take more work to set up the equivalents of all your precedent formulas/calculations in VBA/code, but because you won't be interacting with the spreadsheet, the trade-off may be worth it.

Comment: Other points are how large is `iterations` (what values does it typically range between) and are you also testing different distributions (such that `total iterations` will be `number of distributions × number of iterations per distribution`)?